# searching for a date in a range of dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date, range, formulas, vba

I am working on trying to find a formula or a macro that will help allow me find a particular date in a range of two dates.  I have tried a few different things, but I have come up empty.  Are there any solutions for this? I have 3 date strings, and I am looking to see if the third date falls in the range.

ex. date range is var1 5/1/17 through var2 5/7/17 and I am looking to see if var3 5/5/17 falls within that week. output true if true, false if false.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean to "Find a date"? Do you want to return that date? Return the cell address it's in, etc.? What have you tried, please share any attempts you've made with us, and comments as to why they aren't doing what you want. Also, some sample data and sample expected output would help.

Comment: from what I have googled I have used the couple of formulas below. I get that some of them may not be ideal, but I was just using trial and error.                                                                                                                                                                                                                           =IF(F2=MEDIAN(D2:E2),"Yes","No")                                                         =IF(COUNTIF(D:E,K:K),"Yes","No")

Comment: Can you update your OP with what you're trying to find? Are you looking for a median date (meaning, a date in the middle of two other dates)?

Comment: I have 3 date strings the third of which, I am trying to compare if it is between the first two. So the output would only be a true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using formulas, you would do 
`=IF(AND([earliest date]<=[check date],[latest date]>=[check date]),"Yes","No")`.

[image]

If you need it in VBA, you could do something like:

```
Function checkDate(date1 As String, date2 As String, chkDate As String) As String
If date1 <= chkDate And date2 >= chkDate Then
    checkDate = "Falls between!"
Else
    checkDate = "Outside the range"
End If
End Function
```

And run with `=checkDate(A2,B2,C2)`.

Comment: You could run `MIN(A2:B2)` for *[earliest date]* and MAX for the other.

Comment: @Jeeped - Ooh good thinking.  That'd help if they had a larger list. But, OP said they are given three dates, so I figured to do what I did. Good call though, I didn't think of that!

Comment: re: `date1 As String, date2 As String` why *as string* ?

Comment: @Jeeped - ...I don't know, I wasn't sure how the data was presented at all. Is it already in VBA as a String? (OP tagged both `Formula` and `Macro`, and uses `var1` in their post).  I'll wait for OP to come in and give more detail ...which I honestly probably should have done before offering a solution.

Comment: Probably should be `date1 As Date, date2 As Date, chkDate As Date` but I would have used `date1 As Long, date2 As Long, chkDate As Long`. Even if the dates came in as strings it would be hard to use `>` and `<` against each other. Don't think you would get reliable results from comparing strings.

Comment: For the record, this could be tweaked (as @Jeeped mentions), but until any update from OP, the `String` should work. Personally, I'd like to use `Date()` since we're literally comparing dates, but OP uses the word "String" in their post, so I just went with that method...